# pfSense (FreeBSD 14.0) - Prometheus Node Exporter gives log errors - fix or suppress in log

Tags: freebsd, syslog, pfsense

On pfSense, I've enabled Prometheus Node Exporter, but it gives the following log errors each 15 seconds:

```
Feb 15 09:53:57 vault node_exporter[25559]: ts=2024-02-15T08:53:57.164Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=uname duration_seconds=1.9687e-05 err="cannot allocate memory"
Feb 15 09:53:57 vault node_exporter[25559]: ts=2024-02-15T08:53:57.164Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=zfs duration_seconds=1.6108e-05 err="couldn't get sysctl: no such file or directory"
```

This is my Node Exporter settings:

[image]

I'm not sure which collector gives the errors (on second thought, it seems to be some collectors that are not enabled, but still trying to collect). In any case, if I need it I might not be able to disable it, so another option would be to suppress the error messages in the log.

I've tried:

- Setting `--log.level=none`, but this is apparently not a valid log level
- Creating a `01-node-exporter.conf` file to suppress the messages, like this:

  ```
  if $msg contains "collector failed" then {
      stop
  }
  ```

  And put it inside `/var/etc/syslog.d/`. But this doesn't seem to suppress the messages either (this is working for me on Ubuntu).
- I also tried [this advice](https://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/), and instead put this into the `01-node-exporter.conf` file, but to no avail:

  ```
  :msg, contains, "collector failed" ~
  ```

In addition, I've found the `node_exporter` config file, which is located at `/usr/local/etc/rc.conf.d`. This file contains:

```
# This file is generated by the pfSense node_exporter package.
# Do not edit this file, it will be overwritten automatically.

node_exporter_enable="YES"
node_exporter_listen_address="10.10.1.1:9100"
node_exporter_args=" --collector.boottime --collector.cpu --collector.exec --collector.filesystem --collector.loadavg --collector.meminfo --collector.netdev --collector.textfile --collector.time --log.level=error"
```

I'm inclined to think the erroneous log messages is a bug in Node Exporter for FreeBSD (because the collectors `uname` and `zfs` doesn't even seem to be enabled), so the short term solution would be to suppress the log messages.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. I couldn't get any `syslog` configuration to work, but I managed to edit the `node_exporter` config file like this:

```
# This file is generated by the pfSense node_exporter package.
# Do not edit this file, it will be overwritten automatically.

node_exporter_enable="YES"
node_exporter_listen_address="10.10.1.1:9100"
node_exporter_args=" --collector.boottime --collector.cpu --collector.exec --collector.filesystem --collector.loadavg --collector.meminfo --collector.netdev --collector.textfile --collector.time --log.level=error --no-collector.zfs --no-collector.uname"
```

Note that I added `--no-collector.zfs` and `--no-collector.uname` to the `node_exporter_args`. This prevents these collectors from running, and thus the error messages disappear.

I would still like to know how to directly suppress log messages in FreeBSD through the `syslog` configuration, but that'll be another time.